# do i need to make a bootable cd

Tags: system-installation, dvd, cd

I have windows 8, I already choose the option of ***try and install***, and after the computer restarts it doesn't start. I have it mounted on a virtual drive.

Do I need to make a bootable cd if I want to install it?

Comment: I have expanded the comment to a full answer below. You can accept it as the correct one if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of Ubuntu you will need a bootable CD or DVD. Ubuntu 12.04 LTS may fit in a CD, but Ubuntu 13.10 and soon to be released Ubuntu 14.04 LTS won't. You will need a bootable DVD for recent versions of Ubuntu.

Alternately you will need a bootable USB drive of 1GB or more.

Ubuntu won't install from a virtual drive as you can't boot your computer from it.

Installing Ubuntu on a computer that came pre-installed with Windows 8 can be complicated. See [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) for details.

Hope this helps